# Anaconda environment bash prefix too long

Tags: bash, anaconda, python-venv, ps1

I created an anaconda environment in a project folder specifying the path with -p option, i.e. not in the default anaconda3/envs folder:

```
conda create -p venv
```

The problem is that when I activate that environment, the bash prefix in the terminal is too long, i.e. it prepends the entire path of the environment to the prompt:

```
(/path/to/the/environment/venv) user@machine: ~/path/to/environment/$
```

Is there a way to fix this, meaning make it shorter or delete the prefix from prompt?

My $PS1:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

Comment: Configure your `$PS1` variable, try replacing `\w` by `\W`.

Comment: @choroba I now get (/path/to/the/environment/venv) user@machine:environment/$

Comment: Please include the contents of `$PS1` into your question

Comment: Just put `export PS1='$ '`.  Your prefix will be only `$ `, solving the too long problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Conda Prompt Customization

Since [Conda v4.6.0](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/release-notes.html#improvements) there has been the `env_prompt` configuration option to provide for customization of the PS1 change.  Here is the description:

```
$ conda config --describe env_prompt
# # env_prompt (str)
# #   Template for prompt modification based on the active environment.
# #   Currently supported template variables are '{prefix}', '{name}', and
# #   '{default_env}'. '{prefix}' is the absolute path to the active
# #   environment. '{name}' is the basename of the active environment
# #   prefix. '{default_env}' holds the value of '{name}' if the active
# #   environment is a conda named environment ('-n' flag), or otherwise
# #   holds the value of '{prefix}'. Templating uses python's str.format()
# #   method.
# # 
# env_prompt: '({default_env}) '
```

One option that would help with your case would be to just use the `{name}` variable

```
conda config --set env_prompt '({name}) '
```

which will show only the env's folder name. E.g., your example would be

```
(venv) user@machine: ~/path/to/environment/$
```

Note, this will make it so that when the **base** env is active the prompt will show `(anaconda3)` instead of `(base)`; otherwise, the other named envs should appear as usual.

If you really can't stand that, you could run `basename {default_env}` to get the same result as `{name}` on unnamed envs and still retain `base`.  That is,

```
conda config --set env_prompt '(\$(basename {default_env})) '
```

Comment: Thank you!  All of this works for me but with a small correction: ```conda config --set env_prompt '($(basename {default_env})) ' ```

Comment: I want to only display the parent folder name of the environment, so for prefix "/Users/username/code/llama.cpp/.env", I would like to see "llama.cpp" (i.e. the git repo name), and for named conda envs I want to see the name as usual.
From you solution I tried to set `conda config --set env_prompt '($(basename $(dirname {prefix}))) '` but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Running conda 23.3.1 on macOS, zsh shell.

Comment: @artofbeinghuman for me it worked  `conda config --set env_prompt '($(basename $(dirname {prefix}))) '` (running conda 23.1.0 on Ubuntu 18, bash)

Answer (score 0):

From [Conda's documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment),

After activating an environment using its prefix, your prompt will look similar to the following:

```
(/absolute/path/to/envs) $
```

This can result in long prefixes:

```
(/Users/USER_NAME/research/data-science/PROJECT_NAME/envs) $
```

To remove this long prefix in your shell prompt, modify the env_prompt setting in your .condarc file:

```
$ conda config --set env_prompt '({name})'
```

This will edit your .condarc file if you already have one or create a .condarc file if you do not.

Now your command prompt will display the active environment’s generic name, which is the name of the environment's root folder:

```
$ cd project-directory
$ conda activate ./env
(env) project-directory $
```