# How do I change the name conda displays in parantheses?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have a conda environment that I created with a path (conda create -p /full/path/to/env). When I activate the environment it displays the full path to the environment in parentheses at the beginning of the command prompt line. like
(full/path/to/env) [username@server]

I want to change it so it just shows env instead of full/path/to/env. How do I do that?

I tried adding the directory leading up to my conda environment (i.e. full/path/to)  to my env_dirs configuration using conda config but that didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Anaconda environment bash prefix too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619347/anaconda-environment-bash-prefix-too-long)

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it looks like I'm running an earlier version of conda 4.5.1. I can't update it since I'm not the admin.

Comment: Okay, I'll pull the close vote, but you should explicitly mention "pre-Conda v4.6" in the question. I'm not sure to what extent PS1 changes are customizable in v4.5. Maybe have a look at the `conda config --describe`. If you can disable the PS1 change, you could manually do something like `PS1="$(basename $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV) "` plus whatever else you want in there.