# Conda forgets about the base environment name after deactivating another environment

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda, environment, prompt

I stored my conda environments in a folder called `conda_envs` and I created there an environment called `my_env`.  In order to avoid having the full path printed as part of my prompt, I create a `.condarc` file with the instruction:

```
env_prompt: ({name})
```

Everything works well except for one annoying detail.  As expected, when I log into my account I get a prompt like:

```
(base) dir$
```

And my environments are also listed as expected:

```
base      *  /SomeWhere/Miniconda3/4.7.12.1
my_env       /SomeWhereElse/conda_envs/my_env
```

But after activating and deactivating `my_env`, my prompt becomes:

```
(4.7.12.1) dir$
```

How could I get back to my original prompt?

```
(base) dir$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anaconda environment bash prefix too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619347/anaconda-environment-bash-prefix-too-long)

Comment: Yes, this was it but I needed to introduce a small correction: ```conda config --set env_prompt '($(basename {default_env})) ' ```